# common intranet service to reflect IP address

Tags: networking, ip, ping, internet, ipv4

#### how can I get my apparent intranet IP Address (i.e. my VPN address) using a common service or hack within the intranet?

A useful Internet service is `http://ifconfig.me` which reflects the apparent Internet IPv4 Address back.

```bsh
$ curl ifconfig.me
62.4.22.87
```

Website *ifconfig.me* is similar to website *whatismyip.com* but command-line friendly.

I'm looking for a similar service (or protocol hack) that ***I can use within an intranet (i.e. a corporate VPN)***.

**Is there some hack or tool that can be used *within a typical corporate intranet* to show the apparent IPv4 address (i.e. my VPN IP Address)? (but without querying the local system, e.g. not using `ip` or `ifconfig`).**

For example, is there a special HTTP Request to a Web Server within the intranet that will reveal my VPN IPv4 Address?
Or, is there an obscure SMTP command sent to the corporate email server that will reveal my apparent VPN IPv4 Address?
Perhaps the `ping` tool can reveal it?

I want to run this process within a WSL2 instance (Linux in Windows). The WSL2 instance does not know about the VPN interface managed by Windows. So tools `ip` and `ifconfig` are not adequate.
I cannot setup my own custom service on the intranet.

Comment: I added an answer of using `ssh` and `SSH_CONNECTION`. However, I'm hoping for a less heavyweight approach.

Comment: i think that the email header of any message you send contains your IP address ... sendyourself an email and check the headers ... you could also try pinging your PC by name

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways of doing so:

```bsh
ping -4  $(hostname) 

Pinging DESKTOP-MYHOSTNAME [10.4.0.10] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.4.0.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

```bsh
hostname -i 

10.4.0.10 192.168.230.1 192.168.1.100 0.0.0.0 [other IPv6 addresses]
```

```bsh
netstat -nt | tail -n +2 | tr -s ' ' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" |:"}{print $4}' | uniq

Local
0.0.0.0
10.4.0.10
127.0.0.1
192.168.1.100
192.168.230.1
```

You should also be able to run `route -n` which will also show you how things get routed between interfaces.

Comment: Thanks @Neticegear . I should mention I'm using WSL2 instance which further clouds the VPN IP addresses (I updated the original post).
I tried `ping`, `hostname`, and `netstat` but they did not reveal the VPN Address. They only reveal the private IP Address used by the WSL2 instance.

Comment: You can try accessing the routing table with either `route -n` or  `netstat -r` . Also, since this internal IP likely gets assigned automatically by DHCP, using `netstat -un` will show a UDP connection being made between your internal IP port 68 and the DHCP servers IP on port 67.

Comment: I forgot about calling Windows executables from WSL2. Great suggestion. This works `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/netsh.exe interface ipv4 show addresses name="VPN" | grep -Fe 'IP Address:' | tr -d ' ' | cut -f 2 -d ':'` .
I'll leave the original question up, because I think it's worthwhile.

Comment: where did my `netsh` comment go??? glad you saw it though!

Comment: _where did my netsh comment go???_
I saw your comment in an email but it disappeared here. very strange.

Answer (score 1):

This little `python` script effectively returns the same as https://ifconfig.me

You can host it on a webserver with `python` and call it with `curl`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import html

def header():
    print("Content-type: text/plain")
    print()
def main():
    header()
    print(html.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks @Panki . However, I'm unable to run any of my own services.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon The tool has to be remote. Example, using ssh requires a *remote* sshd server. The tool is not the ssh command, but the sshd remote service. So I'm surprised you asked this question if you are not able to run any of your own services.

Answer (score 0):

I can login to a stable SSH server and echo the environment variable `SSH_CONNECTION`.

An example value of `SSH_CONNECTION` is `10.10.0.23 60123 172.1.0.1 22`. The apparent intranet IP Address `10.10.0.23` could be extracted using `cut`.

```bsh
$ ssh user@ssh-server.local 'echo $SSH_CONNECTION' | cut -f1 -d' '
10.10.0.23
```

A problem with this is it requires manual user input of a password, or an ssh key setup, among other security-sensitive problems.